Almost sure bound on maximum degree of Erdos Renyi Graph
My question arises from the proof of theorem 1.2 in

Alon, N., Mcdiarmid, C. and Reed, B. (1991), Acyclic coloring of graphs. Random Struct. Alg., 2: 277-288.

One wants to bound the probability of the maximum degree of an Erdos-Renyi graph exceeding some value.
The probability for choosing an edge there is $$ p= c \Bigl( \frac{\log n}{n}\Bigr)^{1/4} $$
Then "by standard estimates on binomial distributions" it follows that $$ Pr[ d \leq 2 c n^{3/4} (\log n)^{1/4} ] \rightarrow 1 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$
I dont really get this argument. The authors refer to

Bollobás B. Random Graphs. 2nd ed. Cambridge University Press; 2001.

but I dont see where this result is coming from.
Is there some known almost sure bound for the maximum degree of a random graph in terms of the probability $p$?

The degree distribution of an Erdős–Rényi random graph is a binomial distribution, and the standard estimate is a Chernoff bound: if a binomial random variable $\mathbf X$ has mean $\mu$, then for all $\delta \ge 0$, $$\Pr[\mathbf X \ge (1 + \delta)\mu] \le \exp(-\delta^2 \mu/(\delta + 2))$$ and in particular $\Pr[\mathbf X \ge 2\mu] \le \exp(-\mu/3)$.
In an Erdős–Rényi random graph with edge probability $p$, the average degree is $(n-1)p$, so the probability that a vertex has degree $2(n-1)p$ or more is $\exp(-(n-1)p/3)$. This means that there are $n \cdot \exp(-(n-1)p/3)$ vertices with degree $2(n-1)p$ or more, in expectation.
If, for example, we know that $(n-1)p/3 > 2 \log n$, or $p > \frac{6 \log n}{n-1}$, then this expected value is bounded by $n \exp(-2\log n) = n^{-1}$, so with high probability no vertex exceeds degree $2(n-1)p$. The constant $6$ is not the best here; we could get better values by being more precise.
However, $p = c(\frac{\log n}{n})^{1/4}$ is certainly much bigger than $p = \frac{6 \log n}{n}$ for large $n$, so this bound definitely applies in the case in the question. We have $2(n-1)p < 2cn^{3/4}(\log n)^{1/4}$, and we conclude that with high probability, no vertex has a degree this large.
